# Jquery: Can we use variable in css property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a multi language website, I wanna change my container position according to language. For this I have to change its position accordingly I tried below code.

```
prop = lang == 'ar' ? 'right' : 'left';
$('#head').css({ prop : 200 });
```

But I am unable to achieve this, when I put static property then its working. I know there are other ways but Is it not possible like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the version of css that required named properties. Use the other version.

```
prop = lang == 'ar' ? 'right' : 'left';
$('#head').css(prop, "200");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create the object first, and then pass it into the css function.

```
prop = lang == 'ar' ? 'right' : 'left';
var styles = {};
styles[prop] = 200;
$('#head').css(styles);
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work. Will mark it as an answer once it allow me.

Comment: For the record, in ES6 you can use computed property names.

Comment: @DanishAdeel: Sure it works, but why add 2 extra lines of code and the extra complexity when you can just use `$('#head').css(prop, "200");`? :)

Comment: @GoneCoding That's fine until you want to set more than one property at a time.

Comment: @GoneCoding I have just checked your answer which is also solved my problem, I wish I can mark both of you as Correct Answer :)

Comment: @Brian: Given the example in the question, that's exactly what they want to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like below:

```
var prop = lang == 'ar' ? 'right' : 'left';
var cssObj = {};
cssObj[prop] = 200;
$('#head').css(cssObj);
```